# How should I develop a webpage that could be printed with high precision

Tags: pdf, printing, cross-browser, cross-platform, driver

I am tasked with developing an on-line form that would then be printed to a pre-printed form. This form would later be scanned and OCR-ed and the specifications require a less-than 1mm offset from fields on printed form.

I spent a few hours setting typeset and margins in CSS for perfect alignment, only to find out that on a printer of a different brand the result was almost 5mm off. I then tried rendering the whole form as a PDF before printing, but the results showed that various printers have different margins for printable area.

So I thought of creating an executable that would read this values from the printer driver and align the PDF/image accordingly. I also had an idea that this information could perhaps be gained with a browser add-on/plugin but before starting work on that I would like to ask what do you think would be the best way of solving this alignment problem, preferably so it would work cross-platform(win, linux, mac) and cross-browser (IE, FF, chrome)?

Comment: I have seen a few web pages that were printing things that had to be of the right size--and they all instructed you to turn off scaling.  This accurately preserved the dimensions of the original.  The position on the page didn't matter in any of these cases so I have no idea if it fixed that or not.

Comment: Scaling improved positioning for a few mm when printing the webpage, yes, but it was still not consistent between printers. I think the only way is to get this fixed on a per-printer basis

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that it is impossible to use html to do typesetting reliably. The design of the web has no concern whatsoever about laying text out on a page.

Forget the browser-plugin, that is an enormous hassle to reinvent a solution to a solved problem.

What you should do, is have the form submitted, then generate a PDF specifically to fit the form (or just generate the entire form right then and there). Don't try to render the webpage as a PDF, but use one of the many available PDF generation libraries to straight up generate a PDF, then send that to the user. Yeah, it might be kind of annoying having to maintain essentially 2 chunks of code, one for the webpage and one for the form, but it will be substantially less hassle than coming up with a along the lines of what you are asking for.

That suggestion is of course is ignoring the complete absurdity of generating a printout, to just be OCRed later. If you can eliminate that, you could bypass all of this nonsense.

Comment: I would avoid printing if I could, but it is not possible as it is a government-dictated form and procedures about it.
I actually did use PDFsharp to re-render all forms exactly as they should be printed, and set properties (page.Size to A4; page.TrimMargins to 0, tried some other things too) but still left and top margin differ from printer to printer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use CSS @media print first, and then use exact scaling of a standard unit such as inch, em, and point instead of pixel.
You still have to experiment with different web browsers (e.g. at least IE 10+, Firefox 28+, Chrome 21+) and then try to print it with different types of printers: laser, thermal and inkjet.

There are cases that for some printers, they don't respect standard normal unit of printings but this can be the subject of faulty printer driver used.

There's no single hammer for all kinds of combination of printers and web browsers. So, experience and experiments especially with real printers are common to have.

Comment: Actually I did experiment with that a lot and the most consistent solution was to use mm as units. The sizes on webpage were not that important to me and they looked odd, but when printed the result was very good. My main problem is the top and left offset which are different for each printer.

Comment: @Spikolynn hi, please mark which answer that satisfy your need.

Comment: Hi, sadly no answer satisfies me yet. Perhaps try re-reading my question as I have clarified the problem a bit more since you answered.